# Scrape all this links

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape [this link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esES858ES858&sxsrf=ALeKk00vAYRnHmOE6qFRilFVywG3lzWqrg:1593765601198&q=liga%20acb&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1o7E17DqAhXGSsAKHfPfB5EQBSgAegQIDBAq&biw=958&bih=927#sie=lg;/g/11hz1p2mky;3;/m/04mds4;mt;fp;1;;)
After clicking that link, you will see a lot of basket games. I would like to **scrape** all of them. But I do not know how to do it automatically.
For example: [Scrape 1](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esES858ES858&sxsrf=ALeKk00vAYRnHmOE6qFRilFVywG3lzWqrg:1593765601198&q=liga%20acb&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1o7E17DqAhXGSsAKHfPfB5EQBSgAegQIDBAq&biw=958&bih=927#sie=m;/g/11fwdhwb04;3;/m/04mds4;dt;fp;1;;), [Scrape 2](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esES858ES858&sxsrf=ALeKk00vAYRnHmOE6qFRilFVywG3lzWqrg:1593765601198&q=liga%20acb&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1o7E17DqAhXGSsAKHfPfB5EQBSgAegQIDBAq&biw=958&bih=927#sie=m;/g/11fwdhvh50;3;/m/04mds4;dt;fp;1;;) and [Scrape 3](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esES858ES858&sxsrf=ALeKk00vAYRnHmOE6qFRilFVywG3lzWqrg:1593765601198&q=liga%20acb&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1o7E17DqAhXGSsAKHfPfB5EQBSgAegQIDBAq&biw=958&bih=927#sie=m;/g/11fwdhvh50;3;/m/04mds4;dt;fp;1;;)

I only have this:

```
urlMom = "https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_esES858ES858&sxsrf=ALeKk00vAYRnHmOE6qFRilFVywG3lzWqrg:1593765601198&q=liga+acb&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1o7E17DqAhXGSsAKHfPfB5EQBSgAegQIDBAq&biw=958&bih=927#sie=lg;/g/11hz1p2mky;3;/m/04mds4;mt;fp;1;;" 
page = requests.get(urlMom)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("div", class_="imspo_mt__mit")
```

But it does not even work

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by scrapping? Deleting it after you've clicked on it? Or is this simply a type, and you meant to write "scrape"?

Comment: Have you tried scraping class "tns-c imspo_mt__tt-w imspo_mt__dt-t" instead? That should be the same without the final-value, or "ellipsisize" for the teams and imspo_mt__tt-w for the scores.

Comment: @HavardKleven it just returns an empty variable. And yes, i mean scrape

Comment: Hm, okay - that was a bit strange. You should try going through the classes one by one and see what kind of values the return. I guess you've already done this, but I think your issue is only a matter of finding the correct classes.

Comment: @HavardKleven can you please write the code you've used?